# Reverse a simple equation of value to scale

Tags: optimization

I'm trying reverse the following equation, consider this:

[image]

i've done this to get a value to scale from Max to Min, example i put a x value bigger then i get a small value, so i've tried reverse and i've done something like this:

[image]

but i have not got back to the original value, what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you looking for the inverse of the function $f(x)=\frac {\sqrt x}x$?

Comment: Note:  if that is what you are asking, note that $f(x)=\frac 1{\sqrt x}$.

Comment: @lulu exactly, I want to come back to the value obtained by that formula...

Comment: Ok, well then note that your function simplifies to $\frac 1{\sqrt x}$.  Can you see the inverse now?

Comment: @lulu allright, you do not understand me, i do example: `(sqrt(40) / 40)` and i get `0.158114`, and you suggest that I should do: `(1 / sqrt(40))` for reverse it ?

Comment: No...Your function is $f(x)=\frac 1{\sqrt x}$.  I mean that this is the same function as $\frac {\sqrt x}{x}$.  I am pointing it out because it makes it obvious what the inverse function should be.

Comment: Just to be clear:  if $y=\frac 1{\sqrt x}$ then $x=\frac 1{y^2}$.  Thus the inverse function you seek is $f^{-1}(x)=\frac 1{x^2}$.

Comment: To use your example, $f(40)=\frac 1{\sqrt {40}}=0.158113883$.  If we then apply $f^{-1}$ we get $f^{-1}(0.158113883)=\frac 1{(0.158113883)^2}=40$ as desired.

Comment: @lulu i'm so silly, sorry, i had forgotten that  root to -1 it's the inverse to x value...thanks so much...

Comment: Oh, no problem at all.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to undo the original function, let $f(x)=v=\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt x}{x}$, then, to calculate $f^{-1}(x)$, all that needs to be done is you need to solve for the following $x$:

$v=\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}$

square both sides

$v^2=\displaystyle\frac{1}{x}$

attain the reciprocal

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{v^2}=x$

and then swap the variables

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{x^2}=v$

hence, $f^{-1}(x)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{x^2}$

To confirm whether or not what we have written is true, we can take the rule that $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$, so lets substitute in $x=2$.

$f^{-1}(2)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2^2}=\frac{1}{4}$

$\displaystyle f(\frac{1}{4})=\frac{\sqrt\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot4=2$

We can go further to prove that in this case $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$ if we were to use induction on $x$.